# How to unregister multiple Broadcast receiver which are in different classes at a time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i want to unregister some broadcast receivers with single click.here is the flow.. lets say in Activity A i have below broadcast receivers.

```
    public BroadcastReceiver upload = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };

 public BroadcastReceiver download = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
```

and in Activity B i have below broadcast receivers

```
 public BroadcastReceiver wifi = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };

 public BroadcastReceiver data = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
```

my problem is i want to unregister all these BroadcastReceiver from Activity C with a button click. How can i do that? and how can i check is receiver is registered or not..?

Comment: Unfortunately no API to check if a given broadcastreceiver is registered :( you can only try to unregister and `catch` the exception

Comment: @ArsenyLevin what about unregistering all at a time ?

Comment: Why don't you just send an "unregister" broadcast on the button click?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim how can i do that ..all broadcastreceiver are in different class or activity and i want to do this from different activity

Comment: @GajuKollur `context.sendBroadcast(Intent)`. Just create and action name, smth like `com.example.UNREGISTER_RECEIVER` and make sure they are all registered (intent filter) to this action name. Then call `context.unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver)` from `onReceive`

Answer (score 2):

Keeping broadcast receiver register even after activity is out of screen is memory leak and you should not do that.

Always register your broadcast receivers in onStart/onCreate/onResume and unregister them in onStop/onDestroy/onPause.

Why do you need to keep receiver active even in case activity is out of screen? You might as well use Android Service if you want something to execute out of activity scopes.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create an Interface in your Activity C with a method unresisterRegisters()
2. Implement this Interface In Activity A and B. Overrrid the method and write code for unregistere Receivers
3. create object of A and B in Activity C inside OnButton click and call unresisterRegisters() method with both methods.

I hope this will help You.

Comment: You should never create activity object inside other activity. Very bad architecture.